# How to unpivot certain columns from a delimited file as rows?

Tags: bash

I have a file that as columns such as A, B, C, D, N01, N02,...,N5, T01,...T5

For Example.

```
A01,B01,C01,0,1,2,3,4,5,101,102,103,104,105
A02,B02,C02,0,1,2,3,4,5,101,102,103,104,105
A01,B01,C01,1,11,12,13,14,15,111,112,113,114,115
A02,B02,C02,1,11,12,13,14,15,111,112,113,114,115
```

Depending on the value of D, if it is 0 or 1, I want the output to be the following. This keeps A through D as is and keeps only one of Nxx, Txx, and a counter xx

```
A01,B01,C01,0,1,101,1
A01,B01,C01,0,2,102,2
A01,B01,C01,0,3,103,3
A01,B01,C01,0,4,104,4
A01,B01,C01,0,5,101,5
...
A02,B02,C02,1,11,111,1
A02,B02,C02,1,12,112,2
A02,B02,C02,1,13,113,3
A02,B02,C02,1,14,114,4
A02,B02,C02,1,15,115,5
```

I could manually write a cut command and repeat 5 times, but was looking for a more elegant scriptable solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
{
  for(i=5;i<10;i++){
    print $1,$2,$3,$4,$i,$(i+5),++count
  }
  count=""
}
'   Input_file
```

Comment: Thank you @RavinderSingh13.  That was perfect.

Comment: Updated script based on @RavinderSing13.
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{for (m=5; m<=9; m++) {for (i=1; i<=4; i++) {printf "%s%s", $i, OFS} t=m+5; printf "%s%s%s%s", $m, OFS, $t,","++count "\n"}count="" }'